# Crystal Report Display Sum on bottom only

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

So i have this subreport with values from left corner, then i have formula which sums all the left corner values and display it in the button right corner besides the last left value 
[The actual image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7bOg.jpg)

my problem is that i want to remove the "php 0.00" above , i tried "Suppress if Zero" but if the total sum is Zero it wont display because of that

heres the code of my formula field

`Shared CurrencyVar myTotal ;
if isnull({CashBank.B_Amount}) then 0 else 
if (onLastRecord) then myTotal:= Sum({@convert})`

Currencyvar mytotal -> sum of all values
if the value from the left is null will display 0 
but if not then sum the values

im using SAP Crystal Reports runtime Engine for .Net Framework (32-bit) 13_0_22

p.s ignore th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to achieve this goal:

1. Right-mouse click on {CashBank.B_Amount} and select Insert --> Running Total. This should add the total that keeps tallying for each details row.
2. Right-mouse click on this newly created RunningTotal field, and select "Format Object" --> Common tab --> Suppress --> click the formula button. And for the formula enter: 
   (onLastRecord=false)

This should suppress the running total for all but the last line.